# How to specify recursive element structure in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the next XML:

```
<Property path="something">

          <Property path=".id">
            <Property path=".id1">
              <Property path=".id2">
                <Property path=".id3>
                  <![CDATA["data"]]>
                </Property>
              </Property>
            </Property>
          </Property>

          <Property path=".id4">
            <![CDATA["data"]]>
          </Property >

        </Property>
```

What should I write in my XSD in order to allow me to have as many property nodes as I want. I don't want to write like this:

```
<xs:element name="Property">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Property" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>

...
```

Ignore the validation of the XML. It is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

To build a recursive structure of nested `Property` elements, refer back to the parent element within its content model via `@ref`:

```
<xs:element name="Property">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Property" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
    <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: The 'Property' element was not declared.